# Как получить дату в формате yyyyMMdd?

Tags: javascript

Как получить сегодняшнее число 20.12.2021 (или любое другое в таком формате), чтобы оно было преобразовано в такой вид: 20211220?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const date = Date.now(); // timestamp какого-либо дня
const anotherDate = new Date('2021-01-01');

// доп форматирование значений с одним числом
const format = (date) => date < 10 ? `0${date}` : date.toString();

const getDateString = (timestamp) => {
  const date = new Date(timestamp);
  const day = date.getDate();
  const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  return `${year}${format(month)}${format(day)}`;
};

console.log(getDateString(date)); // 20211220
console.log(getDateString(anotherDate)); // 20210101
```

Comment: Главное помнить, что `new Date('2021-01-01').getMonth()` будет 1, а не 01 (как и для дня). Так что если для формата критично, можно сделать `(new Date('2021-01-01').getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')` что бы забить нулями.

Comment: @PZBird ага, добавил в решение

Answer (score 0):

Более лаконичное решение:

```js
function fd(date) {
  return ['year', 'month', 'day'].map(e => new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
    [e]: 'numeric',
  }).format(date).padStart(2, '0')).join``;
}

console.log(fd(new Date));
console.log(fd(new Date(2021, 1, 1)));
```